# Why add void before methods?

Tags: function, methods, void

Why do you need to add the keyword void before certain methods. I know it means the method returns nothing (or at least that's what I think it means), but why should you add void even if you already know the method is supposed to return nothing?

Comment: Maybe you know it returns nothing, but how does the compiler (or anyone else) know what it's supposed to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tell *the compiler* that the method is supposed to return nothing.

This kind of redundancy allows the compiler to tell you if you make a mistake somewhere.
(eg, forgetting a `return` statement)